# error running my .apk file android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fullscreen

hye.. I'm creating an app using android studio. My app (android 4.4.4) consist of webview activity and works fine until I added fullscreen activity. When i tried installing the .apk file in my phone, app crashed after the splashscreen activity runs.

Then i tried to create new project excluding the full screen activity which i copied my previous code. I run my app (4.4.4) in android virtual device and it works perfectly but when i generate the .apk file then install it in my phone, app crashed, still the same problem. I'm using samsung ace j1. I just couldn't get it.

Can you help me sort this thing out? I'm still a newbie.

Comment: Try your app in `debug mode` with your phone and let me know the results

Comment: i saved the result in .txt and downloaded it in dropbox...click this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgdd3ho34syw3xt/logcat%20from%20debug.txt?oref=e&n=76290167

Comment: can i have your email?i'll send it to your email as well...thank you very much !!